# C: Cast void (*)(void *) to void (*)(char *)

Tags: c, casting, function-pointers

If I try to call a function with a parameter `void (*)(char *)` with an actual `void (*)(void *)` I get this error:

```
note: expected ‘void (*)(char *)’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)(void *)’
```

Isn't it allowed to cast `void (*)(void *)` to `void (*)(char *)`? If not, why not?
If it is safe, how can the error be suppressed without suppressing all casting errors.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us an example of an actual call. Why not cast the _argument_ in the call?

Comment: Typecasting is rarely 'safe'. Usually, casting a larger type to `char*` or any type to `void*` and back to the same type are probably the only generically 'safe' casts. Looks like you are casting function pointer types. This can potentially cause problems depending on the ABI of the platform you are on. For example, in this case, there could, be an argument pushed on the stack that is never popped back because the callee expects no arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree there *should* be 'assignment compatibility' when passing in an actual parameter of type `void (*)(void *)` when `void (*)(char *)` is expected.

To some this may seem strange, as `void *` is the lesser specific type, so you shouldn't be allowed to assign it to a parameter or variable of type `char *`. But in this case it is the other way around. That is sometimes described as 'contravariance'. It is best demonstrated with an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char globalData[10];

void PassHello(void (*func)(char *))
{
    char *text = "hello";
    func(text);
}

void CopyData(void *source)
{
    memcpy(globalData, source, sizeof globalData);
}

void CopyHello(void)
{
    PassHello(CopyData);
}   

int main()
{
    CopyHello();
    puts(globalData);
}
```

There should be no problem for `func(text)` to make the call to `CopyData`. Even though `CopyData` is declared to accept `void *` as a parameter, it should also accept a more specific type, in this case `char *`.

It is counter-intuitive, but true: `void (*)(void *)` as a type **is more specific** than `void (*)(char *)`. *That* is what contravariance is all about.

Unfortunately, the C language does not care about contravariance, allowing implicit pointer conversions for naked `void *` only. Compilers could implement this as a language extension, but current major compilers don't.

Consequently, the code above gives a type error.

**Note:**
As pointed out by other posters, the type error is justified by the fact that the C standard does not guarantee different pointer types to be compatible. C compilers can take the liberty to generate different code depending on the type of a pointer. It's theoretically possible to make this work for 'nested' types too (in this case, the type of the parameter(s) of a function pointer), but compiler complexity would probably explode. So it made sense to draw a line somewhere; C is not Haskell.

I think the cleanest solution (i.e. not involving explicit typecasts) is to make a 'wrapper' function around the `void (*)(void *)` function pointer. For example:

```
void CopyCharData(char *source)
{
    CopyData(source);
}
```

And then pass the wrapper instead:

```
PassHello(CopyCharData);
```

This will compile and run just fine.

Live demo:
https://repl.it/repls/ImmediateWindingOrders

Comment: Well, the C compilers don't support it because the C language does not allow for contravariance. C does not have any pattern-matching kind of rules wrt. function argument types like C++ does, the only implicit pointer conversion that it allows is that to/from a naked `void*` (which C++ forbids). All other pointer conversions require a cast.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Thank you for pointing that out. I should have made it clearer I was refering to contravariance not as a language feature but as a concept to argue OP's scenario is type-safe. The fact that contravariance is not part of the C language design, does not imply the scenario is type-unsafe in C. The fact you can work your way around the type error with something as simple as a wrapper function, proves my point. The wrapper function is not a hack; it is a perfectly normal language feature.

Comment: In that case, I suggest that you turn "Unfortunately, most (all?) C compilers do not support contravariance" into something like "Unfortunately, the C language does not care about contravariance, allowing implicit pointer conversions for naked `void*`, only. Compilers could implement this as a language extension, but current major compilers don't".

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Thanks; I liked your suggestion so much I edited it in verbatim.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Just checking... You mentioned "allowing implicit pointer conversions for naked void*, only", which seems to suggest you were under the impression my solution relies on the fact that C allows an implicit downcast from `char *` to `void *`. Please note it is not; these are _all_ upcasts. It would work equally well in other strongly-typed languages.

Comment: The C language allows both: `void* a = (char*)b;` and `char* b = (void*)a;`. And both are used deliberately by accomplished C programmers: For example, if you define a callback as `void (*callback)(void*)`, an implementation often looks like this: `void implementation(void* arg) { MyType* me = arg; /*code using me, not arg*/ }` This implicit downcast has the effect of declaring the expected dynamic type of the argument right at the top of the implementation while allowing the code that performs the callback to be entirely oblivious of the concrete type of the pointer it passes through.

Comment: I am aware C allows implicitly downcasting `void *`, and that there are use cases for it. But in a discussion about type safety, it is off limits. I deliberately did not use _any_ implicit downcasts in my code sample, as it would completely undermine my statement that it is 100% safe to assign a pointer of type `void (*)(void *)` to a variable or parameter of type `void (*)(char *)`.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass an argument for a function parameter that is declared to be a pointer to a function, constraints in the C standard require the argument to be a pointer to a compatible function type (or to be a null pointer constant). For function types to be compatible, their declared parameter types must be compatible. But a `char *` and a `void *` are different types and are not compatible with each other.

In fact, the C standard requires a `char *` and a `void *` to have the same representation and allows them to be easily converted back and forth, but it still specifies that they are not compatible. Among other things, these type rules help catch errors—when a programmer mistypes the name or expression they want to use, the compiler may catch it if the types do not match.

So, a `void (*)(char *)` is not compatible with a `void (*)(void *)`, and, if you try to use one where another is expected, the compiler will warn you.

You can convert one of these pointers to the other type by using an explicit cast. When passing arguments to a function, the rules of the C standard will implicitly convert the argument to the parameter type if certain rules are satisfied. However, the rules for conversions explicitly requested with a cast are broader. You can cast any function pointer to any function pointer type. So, if `x` is a `void (*)(void *)`, you can cast it with `(void (*)(char *)) x`, and you can pass that for a parameter declared to have that type.

However, the fact that you can make that conversion does not guarantee that the pointer will work if used to call a function. The rule allowing function pointers to be converted is primarily intended to allow a function pointer to be temporarily converted to another type to be stored in passed in some common form and later to be converted back to its original type before being used to call a function. The rule allowing conversion does not say a converted function pointer will work if used to call a function with parameters that are not compatible.

Comment: @RuudHelderman: Regardless of your desires for what C should be, use of the converted pointer is not type-safe. If a pointer to a `void ()(void *)` is used to call a `void ()(char *)`, the behavior is not defined by the C standard, and one cannot rely on how a C implementation will behave in that case, in the absence of further guarantees from the C implementation or other sources. Your assertion that it is type-safe may be predicated on some model of how a C implementation behaves, which you have not stated, but the C standard does not use that model, and this conclusion is not justified.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I wasn't aware of this. @GiuseppeGuerrini also did quite some explanation on the potential risks. I guess this implies it's not safe to do an explicit typecast between the two function pointer types. I wonder how many big C projects would still work when a compiler actually employs 'incompatible' pointers.

Comment: @RuudHelderman: They work fine until the optimizer gets aggressive about decisions based on type compatibility. We can no longer reason about how an implementation will behave based on the underlying machine architecture, because optimizers are making decisions based on the theoretical model given by the C standard. Even if a C implementation uses machine instructions with a particular kind of pointer (flat address space, same for all types), the optimizer may cause the C implementation to behave as if that were not so.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the two function pointer types are not equivalent is the possible difference in calling conventions. C does not assumes that `void *` and `char *` parameters are passed in the same way (although on most processors they do). In theory, these types could even have different encodings. So we can't assume that a function that expects a `char *` and a function that expects a `void *` share the same calling convention. That's why the compiler complains.
"You liar! C does let me pass a `char *` to a function that expects a `void *`! I have done it for years!".
C guarantees that all pointers can be safely converted in `void *`(*NOTE: conversion may require some processing, in principle*), and it also applies automatic conversion from `some *` to `void *` when passing arguments, *provided that the compiler knows the original type of arguments and the actual signature of the function*. If the function is invoked by pointer, the compiler must take the function's signature from the type of the variable that carries the function pointer. In your case, the variable is `void (*)(char *)`, so the compiler will generate code to pass a `char *` without converting it to `void *` first, as the actual function would expect. This is a case of undefined behavior.

Comment: `void *` and `char *` cannot have different encodings. C 2018 6.2.5 28 says “A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type.” Footnote 49 says “The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions.” The latter, while non-normative, tells us we ought to be able to pass a `char *` where a function expects a `void *` even if the parameter is not declared (is not in a prototype or is in a `...` portion).

Comment: By a "practical" point of view you are right, but it depends on the exact meaning of "interchangeability of members of unions". In a very rigid interpretation, one could think that it only means that both types need the same storage. But a more reasonable interpretation (like yours) is that we can do "myunion.myvoid=somepchar; strcpy(myunion.mypchar, "xxx");" and get the same effect of "strcpy(somepchar,"XXX");". That is what actually happens on all modern processors, as far as I know.